# JQuery UI Autocomplete select event not updating text box in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Every other aspect of my autocomplete works but I am unable to get this to work solely in IE within other browsers this happens automatically.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
        ptb.val(ui.item.value);
        ptb.blur();
```

Within the above event I assumed that I could assign the value that had been selected from the list to the textbox (**ptb**) this I now see is a mistake when working with IE it does not update?

any quick answers?

I am sure this is something simple I am missing?

Comment: still not working in IE but have realised that my ajax selection could return two methods to the source event the first being the label and the second the value setting the value to that of the selected item has made my code excution quicker and cleaner on other browsers but it has no effect on Internet Exploerer

Comment: Do you see any errors on the page? Can you replicate in an example on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: I will atempt to :) and put the url here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jfTVL/10/

Comment: it works here lol but this is without an ajax call and no select function also this is a simple textbox not an asp.net textbox

Comment: asp.net *should* generate an `input` just like you've written. Are there any errors on the page in IE?

Comment: I have renmoved the select function to try and mimic the success on JSFiddle but unfortunately the textbox still seems to have a "default state" for want of a better term this state seems to be the value that was originally searched within the textbox

Comment: could it be to do with the autopostback? this is enabled for other search features (this textbox is part of a set of filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function()  { 
    var json_out = [{ "id": "654356", "label": "654356", "value": "654356" }, { "id": "654348", "label": "654348", "value": "654348" }];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            response($.map(json_out, function(item) {
                return { label: item.label}
            }))
         }
     });     
});
```